# blockUI scrollable content

Tags: jquery, blockui

I love the blcokUI plugin. I use it all around the place in my projects. Recently, I needed to inject dynamic html inside the blockUI dialog. Basically content are image previews. Most of the time, the space needed for the photos are larger than the screen itself.

I tried a lot of solutions of I can think of, including having a seperate scrollable div inside the blockUI with no luck.

Has anyone ever accomplished this?

**EDIT:**
The code is as follows;

How the blockUI is called:

```
$('#addphoto').click(function (e) {
    $('body').block({ message: $('#dropbox'), css: { top: '10px;', width: '90%', 'position': 'absolute'}, allowBodyStretch: true })
});
```

The dropbox content:

```
<div id="dropbox" style="display:none;"><span class="message">drag&drop images here</span></div>
<div id="image_container">
    <div class="preview done">
        <span class="imageHolder">
            <img src="" />
            <span class="uploaded" style="overflow: scroll"; ></span></span>
        <div class="progressHolder">
            <div class="progress">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited my question to include the code..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `blockMsgClass` parameter in your BlockUI to modify the class used for individual dialogues. 
As these are added inline you will need to include `!important` in order for some css attributes to work.

knowing this you could do something like:

```
$('#addphoto').click(function (e) {
    $('body').block({ 
       blockMsgClass: 'PhotoAdd',
       message: $('#dropbox') 
     })
});
```

then in your css:

```
.PhotoAdd{
 Top:10px!important;
 width:90%!important;
 position: absolute!important;
 height:90%!important;
 overflow:auto!important;
}
```

this will make the entire BlockUI dialogue scrollable as needed.